# how use cookie in service angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and want to use the cookie I set into new BehaviorSubject.
Please help me, thanks!

*data.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    a: any;
    private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.a);
    currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private cookie: CookieService) {
        this.a = this.cookie.get('email');
    }
}
```

Comment: What excatly is the problem, please be more specific.

Comment: Please explain better were you need help.

Comment: Hey @javad you need to move the initialization of the BehaviorSubject to the constructor

Comment: regards for comments problem is value a undfined

Comment: @hamilton.lima please show me tanks

Answer (score 1):

Moving the initialization to the constructor

```
export class DataService {

  private messageSource;
  public getCurrentMessage(){
    return this.messageSource.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private cookie: CookieService) {
    let email = this.cookie.get('email');
    this.messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(email);
  }
}
```